# Button instead of appicon and title in android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**What i am trying to do:**

1. I have an activity, on the top instead of app title and icon i am
   trying to implement a button like a back button shown in figure
   below
2. I tried with menu feature but all icons appear on the right side of
   actionbar

---

- Is there any already posted SO-Question on this ?
- Otherwise how to achieve this

---

[image]

***I have the class below***

**MainActivityList.java**

```
public class MainActivityList extends ListActivity  {

    TextView content;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_list);
        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

        String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_selections);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,AndroidMediaPlayer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use custom action bar. create a layout file for your desired action bar and inflate that in activity.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, using action bar needs to follow up design guideline.
For your case, i think that there is no need to use it.

You can use a custom View as ActionBar, it will be simple to customize and design.

see this sample library as an example.
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar